IntelliJ Idea plugin. How to check if it's a Flutter/Dart project
I've started developing a Plugin for Android Studio/IntelliJ Flutter projects written in Dart! I'm just trying to figure out how to hide an action from PopUp list if it's not a Flutter or Dart project.

The current code is:
package org.example.buildrunner

import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionUpdateThread
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent
import com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project

class BuildRunnerAction : AnAction() {
    override fun update(e: AnActionEvent) {
        super.update(e)
        val project: Project? = e.project

        // Disable the action if the project is not a Flutter project
        e.presentation.isEnabled = isFlutterProject(project)
    }

    override fun actionPerformed(e: AnActionEvent) {
        // Get the VirtualFile corresponding to the location where the action was triggered
        val virtualFile: VirtualFile? = e.dataContext.getData("virtualFile") as? VirtualFile

        // Check if the VirtualFile is not null
        if (virtualFile != null) {
            // Get the path to the VirtualFile
            val filePath = virtualFile.path

            // Show the path in a message dialog
            Messages.showMessageDialog(
                e.project,
                "Path to the object: $filePath",
                "Object Path",
                Messages.getInformationIcon()
            )
        } else {
            // If the VirtualFile is null, show an error message
            Messages.showErrorDialog(
                e.project,
                "Unable to retrieve the path to the object.",
                "Error"
            )
        }

    }

    override fun getActionUpdateThread(): ActionUpdateThread {
        return ActionUpdateThread.EDT;
    }

    private fun isFlutterProject(project: Project?): Boolean {
        if (project == null) return false
        
        return true;
    }
}

